# Using Pi to stream audio from PC to stereo

Tags: ubuntu, streaming, pulseaudio

I would like to use my pi to stream the audio from my pc to my stereo. I am using the method described [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/11744).

Unfortunately, my computer does not detect the pi.

Some details about my installation:

It was recommended to make pulseaudio start on boot by adding it to `/etc/default/pulseaudio`. This file did not exist, so I created it. I also added it to the `/home/pi/.bashrc`.

The answer states that you have to whitelist some ip adresses, by adding the following commands to `/etc/pulse/system.pa`

```
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1;192.168.1.0/24
```

Is the second address (192.168.1.0/24) the local ip address? The address of the computer streaming the audio? I added my adress here (got it using ifconfig). Also, what is the `/24`?

Comment: The method described [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/11744) isn't available. What is `/home/pi.bashrc`? Seems there is a typo.

Comment: I can not open the link. Seems to be broken. And you are right. The file is  `/home/pi/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link does not work.
Anyways if you want rpi to behave as a media server check Kodi, Kodi is an os as raspbian and can be used stream/play content on rpi using a desktop/android/ios.